# Can't get this flashing light in javascript to stop flashing with clearInterval

Tags: javascript, clearinterval

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>stoplight</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stoplight.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="controls">
        <button id="stop">Stop</button>
        <button id="slow">Slow</button>
        <button id="go">Go</button>
        <button id="caution">Caution</button>
    </div>
    <div id="mainContainer">
        <div id="top" class="off">
        </div>
        <div id="middle" class="off">
        </div>
        <div id="bottom" class="off">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="stoplight.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically, I'm just trying to select each div of the stoplight and change the background color. First, I thought I could just reset each div to its original color. I'm trying to do the same with the setInterval function that starts a flashing yellow light, but it doesn't seem to stop it and breaks the rest of the functions.

```
document.getElementById('stop').onclick = goRed;
document.getElementById('go').onclick = goGreen; 
document.getElementById('slow').onclick = goYellow;
document.getElementById('caution').addEventListener('click', () => {
    blink();
});

let middle = document.getElementById('middle');
let blinking;

function goRed() {
reset();
document.getElementById('top').style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
};

function goYellow() {
    reset();
    middle.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF00';
};

function goGreen() {
    reset();
    document.getElementById('bottom').style.backgroundColor = '#7FFF00';
};

function blink(){
    reset();
    blinking = setInterval(() => {
    middle.classList.toggle('onYellow');
    }, 1000);
};

function reset() {
    document.getElementById('top').style.backgroundColor = '#A0522D';
    document.getElementById('middle').style.backgroundColor = '#A0522D';
    document.getElementById("bottom").style.backgroundColor = '#A0522D';
    clearInterval(blinking);
 };
```

Comment: Can you provide your CSS as well -- ideally using the code snippet tool so your example can be run/executed in-line within your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing in-style coloring, with class based coloring, and in some cases, the browser will decide which gets a priority. Unless you add `!important` in the class background to enforce the attribute.

I suggest removing all in-style coloring and sticking only to classes so that you will not have to use `!important`. 
This way, it is easier to work with blinking and `setInterval`.

See my code snippet below.

```js
document.getElementById('stop').onclick = goRed;
document.getElementById('go').onclick = goGreen;
document.getElementById('slow').onclick = goYellow;
document.getElementById('caution').addEventListener('click', () => {
  blink();
});

let middle = document.getElementById('middle');
let blinking;

function goRed() {
  reset();
  document.getElementById('top').className = "onRed";
};

function goYellow() {
  reset();
  middle.className = "onYellow";
};

function goGreen() {
  reset();
  document.getElementById('bottom').className = "onGreen";
};

function blink() {
  reset();
  blinking = setInterval(() => {
    middle.classList.toggle('onYellow');
    middle.classList.toggle('onOff');
    
  }, 1000);
};

function reset() {
  document.getElementById('top').className = "onOff";
  document.getElementById('middle').className = "onOff";
  document.getElementById("bottom").className = "onOff";
  clearInterval(blinking);
};
```

```css
#mainContainer div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.onYellow {
   background-color: #ffff00;
}

.onOff {
   background-color: #A0522D;
}

.onGreen {
  background-color: #7FFF00;
}

.onRed {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>stoplight</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stoplight.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="controls">
    <button id="stop">Stop</button>
    <button id="slow">Slow</button>
    <button id="go">Go</button>
    <button id="caution">Caution</button>
  </div>
  <div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="top" class="off">
    </div>
    <div id="middle" class="off">
    </div>
    <div id="bottom" class="off">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="stoplight.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```